# Suddenly 404 errors in cPanel

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, cpanel

We have a shared host And I want to get two sites on addon Domain.

The first site is no problem But the second site is addon Domain II When we go to the WordPress page, we face a strange problem And that's a problem for files too.

For example on this page:
http://song-fa.ir/wp-admin/install.php

Sometimes the page installed and occasionally CPanel 404 Error page.

Even static files such as js file Sometimes also created error 404 Which is specified in the following file:
http://song-fa.ir/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reset the entire host to solve this problem and Do the installation again
Perhaps your problem will be solved